# Why get I 0 value unless I did conditional test

Tags: apache-pig

I want to filter an entiy where MT_V and MT_E should be diffenrent to zeo.

Note that these variables are declared as bigdecimal .

So the command is :

```
S0 = FILTER E1ECP BY ((NO_PCI != '0') AND (MT_V != 0) AND (MT_E != 0));
```

Where NO_PCI  is an other variable.

But I get a line in my data where MT_V ==0.00 and MT_E == 0.00

```
PR,20190711-135040,2018,12,34,001,01,DC03520118,93873104,EUR,L,5A00,3A001,013400,806457,,,0.00,0.00,,2037,CAI,1600,,C1,
```

How do you explain this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (int) to cast on MT_V,MT_E and compare it to 0.

```
S0 = FILTER E1ECP BY ((NO_PCI != '0') AND ((int)(MT_V) != 0) AND ((int)(MT_E) != 0));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but look what I get as problem `Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ROUND as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.`

Comment: what should I do in these case ?

Comment: Try casting to int instead of ROUND like this S0 = FILTER E1ECP BY ((NO_PCI != '0') AND ((int)MT_V != 0) AND ((int)MT_E != 0));